# Attempt to read property on array

Tags: php, arrays, database, properties

i get this error:

```
Warning: Attempt to read property "squadra" on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\statistiche-calcio\index.php on line 57
```

this is the code of my db.php file:

```
    <?php

function connect($dbHost, $dbName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword){

    $db = new mysqli(
        $dbHost, 
        $dbUsername, 
        $dbPassword, 
        $dbName
    );

    if($db->connect_error){
        die("Impossibile connettersi al database \n" . $db->connect_error . "\n" . $db->connect_errno);
    }
    return $db;
}


function fetchAll(mysqli $db, $table){

    $data = [];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";

    $results = $db->query($sql);

    if($results->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $results->fetch_object()){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}



function fetchSquadra(mysqli $db, $table, $squadra){

    $data = [];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = " . $squadra;

    $results = $db->query($sql);

    if($results->num_rows === 1){
        while($row = $results->fetch_object()){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
            
    }
    return $data;
}
```

and this is my index.php where i get the error:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
require_once('db.php');

$db = connect(
    DB_HOST, 
    DB_NAME, 
    DB_USERNAME, 
    DB_PASSWORD,
);

$records = [];

$records = fetchAll($db, 'partite');


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
    table, th, td{
        border: 1px solid grey;
        text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
    <h1>Risultati Premier League</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Data</th>
                <th>Casa</th>
                <th>Risultato</th>
                <th>Ospite</th>
                <th>Risultato 1 tempo</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            if(count($records) > 0):
                foreach($records as $record):
                    $squadra_casa = fetchSquadra($db, 'squadre', $record->squadra_casa);
                    $squadra_ospite = fetchSquadra($db, 'squadre', $record->squadra_ospite);
                    
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $record->id;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $record->data;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $squadra_casa->squadra;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $record->goal_casa . " - ". $record->goal_ospite;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $squadra_ospite->squadra;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $record->goal_casa_1t . " - ". $record->goal_ospite_1t;?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                endforeach;
            else: ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6">Non è stata trovata nessuna partita!</td>
                </tr>
                <?php endif ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have try to var_dump() the variable $squadra_casa and i get this:

> array(1) {
> [0]=>
> object(stdClass)#5 (3) {
> ["id"]=>
> string(2) "18"
> ["squadra"]=>
> string(6) "Fulham"
> ["campionato"]=>
> string(1) "1"
> }
> }

but when i try to echo out the $squadra_casa->squadra property i get the error.

How can i solve it? What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$squadra_casa[0]->squadra`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should try `$squadra_casa[0]->squadra`